# Increase the resolution of the image returned from Facebook GRAPH API

Tags: css, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, facebook-graph-api

I am successful in getting the facebook profile picture from the **`access_token.`**

Here is what the image looks like :

[image]

The img-url returned by the graph api is this :

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/18690_10200566810328735_5541565876879508513_n.jpg?oh=a9e7e2c4e16c1b85c79359c8cf0bdc22&oe=5679B55C&__gda__=1451176224_cd636273f4f2b4ad991a70820d758953
```

What is happening now is that this image is getting stretched(pixels) when set to one of my asp image controls in my website.

Here is the aspx code for the image control :

```
<asp:Image ID="imgPP" runat="server" CssClass="img-thumbnail" Style="position: relative;left: 40px; top: 10px" Height="150px" Width="150px" />
```

The **CSS** is from the template and is a standard **Bootstrap CSS** :

```
 img {
  border: 0;
}
.img-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

How should I maintain the resolution of the image on larger heights and widths ?

**EDIT : 1**

This is how I get the Picture URL from the FacebookID :

```
public static string GetPictureUrl(string faceBookId)
        {
            WebResponse response = null;
            string pictureUrl = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", faceBookId));
                response = request.GetResponse();
                pictureUrl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //catch exception
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null) response.Close();
            }
            return pictureUrl;
        }
```

Comment: You've shown everything except the code that gets the URL from the API which is surely the only thing that you can change that will fix this.

Comment: @DavidG : I am not sure how that will affect that .. Still I all add the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the URL you are calling to request the larger profile picture by adding the `type=large` query string:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type=large
```

The types you can specify are:

```
small
normal
large
square
```

Alternatively you can specify the width and height and Facebook will return the image that most closely matches those dimensions:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?width=500&height=600
```

Comment: If only I could upvote this a million timessss!!! Thank you so much!!! :D (Y) Alternately I had a similar problem where I could not retrieve the `user_location` .. There is no error but an empty string is retrieved from the method.. Here is my method : http://pastebin.com/xMW8um99 .. If you could have a look at it and tell me what is wrong with it! thanks!

Comment: My pleasure to help! Unfortunately I cannot access pastebin from where I am right now (firewall restrictions), also if you need further help you should ask a distinct question so others can help and future visitors can benefit.

Comment: Sure thing! I was confused on which search terms i should use for such a trivial question.. can u tell me some references for future use ? Except , ufcourse this question is all I need for picture url related doubts!

Comment: I cannot suggest a search term as I can't see the code! :)